asymptoticity of partition function as evaluation of singular integral (the Laplace transform of state density function)
This is an example in section 4.4 Evaluation of singular integral of Algebraic Geometry and Statistical Learning Theory (SUMIO WATANABE). At the end of example 4.8, the partition function is calculated by $Z(n) = \int_0^1 v(t)e^{-nt}dt = \int_0^nv(t/n)e^{-t}\frac{dt}{n} = C_1\frac{\log n}{4\sqrt{n}} - C_2\frac{1}{4n}+C_3(n)$, where $C_1,C_2>0$ constants, and $\lim_{n\to\infty} C_3(n)/n=0$.
My question is that if we expand the logarithm in the integral, we get
$$Z(n) = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{n}}\int_0^nt^{-\frac{1}{2}} (-\log t/n)e^{-t}dt= \frac{ \log{n} }{4\sqrt{n}}\int_0^nt^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-t}dt -\frac{1}{4\sqrt{n}}\int_0^nt^{-\frac{1}{2}}( \log{t} )e^{-t}dt.$$
The work so far is similar to the equation stated in the book, but i fail to justify the second $C_2$ term  has  the denominator of n instead of $\sqrt{n}$. And finally, I think that if the upper index of integral is replaced with $\infty$,  the final $C_3$
term actually goes to 0, so it seems not neccesary to divide it by n.
To make sure we are on the same page,  the state density function is defined as: $v(t) = \frac{1}{4}t^{-\frac{1}{2}} (-\log t)$ for $0<t<1$ and $v(t)=0$ otherwise according to the result in the previous section.

For the specific function $v(t)$ you use I don't see the place for the term $\frac{const}n$ . All other asymptotic terms are exponentially small, except for the firts two: $$Z(n)\sim\frac{\Gamma(1/2)}4\frac{\ln n}{\sqrt n}-\frac{\sqrt\pi,\psi(1/2)}4\frac1{\sqrt n}$$

given my experience with Watanabe's book i'd say @Svyatoslav is right, and writing $1/n$ instead of $1/\sqrt{n}$ is a typo

also the $C_3$ term should probably be $C_3(n)/(1/n) \to 0$, ie $C_3(n) = o(1/n)$

@tkw that makes sense, and for the sake of completeness, here's a quick check that $\lim_{n\to\infty} nC_3(n) = 0$: suppose not, say its absolute value is greater than L>0, then by picking a sufficiently large n, the integration of $C_3(n)$ is lowerly bounded by logarithm., this contradicts to the fact that integral of both gamma and its derivatives are upper bounded. Do you have any comment on this check or any better proof for this?

@jorden i'm not sure i follow your idea — i'd prove roughly as follows (though i haven't checked this). the $C_3$ term comes from extending the integrals to infinity, looking at the first expression, $t^{-1/2}(\log (t/n))$ is bounded above for $t$ bounded away from 0, and $\int_n^\infty e^{-t} dt$ is order $e^{-n}$, so $C_3$ is the same. this is much stronger that $o(1/n)$, but i would guess Watanabe mentions this to emphasise that the $C_1,C_2$ terms are of leading order

good luck with this book! it can be a bit opaque but there's definitely some interesting stuff :-)

@tkw thx. and i'm glad to know that someone has read the book and noticed the significance of this area of study!
